# What does upgrading characters do in the Clash of Castles update?

Tags: simpsons-tapped-out

[image]

In the Clash of Castles update, you have the ability to upgrade your castles, with clear and stated advantages to doing so.  (In the screenshot above: "Next Level: Earn 1 Castle Gate").

However, you *also* have the ability to upgrade your characters.  In the screenshot above, my "Barbarian Homer is now Level 4".  It doesn't seem to cost anything, so I have been doing so, but what advantage does it give?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially levelling the barbarian characters (Barbarian Homer, Archer Lisa, Goblin Bart and Wizard Marge) achieves two things, it allows you to complete certain requirements on some  of the quests in the event's questline, and it slightly increases the amount of "elixir" paid out for different tasks.

While none of these are primary sources they do seem to agree on the general facts:

http://simpsonstappedout.wikia.com/wiki/Barbarian_Homer

> The first 10 upgrades give an increase in earnings. After you reached
>   the 10th level a message is shown that Barbarian Homer can be leveled
>   up 1000 levels further more. These bonus levels don't increase the
>   earning anymore but shall be visible for other players after the end
>   of the event.

http://tstoaddicts.com/2014/08/27/character-level-up/

> Character Level Ups are a required element of the event, in order to
>   complete the questlines you’ll have to level up characters to a
>   certain point.
>
> ...
>
> The most common question we’re seeing about Character Leveling up is, What Does it Do?  In short…nothing.  It does very little to impact your characters, however it DOES increase their Elixir payout per task.  As you increase each level you’ll see a slight increase in the amount of Elixir that’s payed out for each task the character skin performs.  Here’s how the Elixir payout increases by Level:

```
For Barbarian Homer:
Task Length
            1hr         4hrs        8hrs        12hrs       16hrs       24hrs
Level 1     1 Elixir    4 Elixir    8 Elixirs   10 Elixirs  16 Elixirs  20 Elixirs
Level 2     2 Elixirs   5 Elixirs   9 Elixirs   11 Elixirs  17 Elixirs  22 Elixirs
Level 3     2 Elixirs   5 Elixirs   10 Elixirs  12 Elixirs  18 Elixirs  23 Elixirs
Level 4     2 Elixirs   5 Elixirs   10 Elixirs  12 Elixirs  18 Elixirs  24 Elixirs
Level 5     2 Elixirs   5 Elixirs   10 Elixirs  13 Elixirs  19 Elixirs  25 Elixirs
Level 6     2 Elixirs   6 Elixirs   11 Elixirs  13 Elixirs  20 Elixirs  26 Elixirs
Level 7     2 Elixirs   6 Elixirs   11 Elixirs  14 Elixirs  21 Elixirs  27 Elixirs
Level 8     2 Elixirs   6 Elixirs   12 Elixirs  14 Elixirs  21 Elixirs  28 Elixirs
Level 9     2 Elixirs   6 Elixirs   12 Elixirs  15 Elixirs  22 Elixirs  29 Elixirs
Level 10    2 Elixirs   6 Elixirs   12 Elixirs  15 Elixirs  23 Elixirs  30 Elixirs
```

And here’s how it changes for Wizard Marge, Goblin Bart & Archer Lisa:

```
Task Length
            1hr         4hrs        8hrs        12hrs       24hrs
Level 1     1 Elixir    4 Elixir    8 Elixirs   10 Elixirs  20 Elixirs
Level 2     2 Elixirs   5 Elixirs   9 Elixirs   11 Elixirs  22 Elixirs
Level 3     2 Elixirs   5 Elixirs   10 Elixirs  12 Elixirs  23 Elixirs
Level 4     2 Elixirs   5 Elixirs   10 Elixirs  12 Elixirs  24 Elixirs
Level 5     2 Elixirs   5 Elixirs   10 Elixirs  13 Elixirs  25 Elixirs
Level 6     2 Elixirs   6 Elixirs   11 Elixirs  13 Elixirs  26 Elixirs
Level 7     2 Elixirs   6 Elixirs   11 Elixirs  14 Elixirs  27 Exlirs
Level 8     2 Elixirs   6 Elixirs   12 Elixirs  14 Elixirs  28 Elixirs
Level 9     2 Elixirs   6 Elixirs   12 Elixirs  15 Elixirs  29 Elixirs
Level 10    2 Elixirs   6 Elixirs   12 Elixirs  15 Elixirs  30 Elixirs
```

The [Simpsons Wiki seems to agree with all of the above](https://simpsonswiki.com/wiki/The_Simpsons:_Tapped_Out_Clash_of_Clones_content_update#Task_rewards).

Edited to add that as well as the upside of increased elixir from jobs there is no downside to upgrading your characters, it doesn't even use up your gold coins. Although the game shows that you need a certain amount of gold coins to upgrade the character, the upgrade process doesn't actually consume the gold coins, you just need to show that you have at least that number of coins as a requirement for the upgrade, you're not buying the upgrade.

From http://tstoaddicts.com/2014/08/27/character-level-up/

> Character Level Ups require Gold. However, to level up a character it
>   will NOT take away Gold from your total.  You’re simply required to
>   have that much Gold on Hand to level the character up.  (for example
>   if you have 2000 Gold on hand, and you need 1,000 to level up Lisa,
>   1,100 to level up Bart and 2,000 to level up Marge you can do all 3 at
>   that point.  It won’t deduct from your total).

I have tested this, and can confirm that no gold coins are taken from your total when upgrading characters.

Answer (score -1):

Some jobs reward elixir, the amout of elixir to give is multiplied by the level of the character